# How can I call an object from Canvas to a character object in Prefabs in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object in Canvas named X and a character object named Y in Prefabs. That Y character has a script Z and in Z script

```
public GameObject X;
```

But as you can guess I can't attach this X object to Y in the inspector because Y is not in hierarchy it is in Prefabs. I tried to get it in void Start method like

```
void Start()
{
   X = GameObject.Find("X");
}
```

But it doesn't work. So is there a way to get that component using code or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Did you instantiate the character Y?

Comment: Yes, I did but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the relationship between scene object & assets (prefabs) is the reverse of your expectations.

You are able to serialize references to Prefabs in Scene GameObject scripts (usually for the purpose of instantiating `GameObjects` from them or for data references in the case of `ScriptableObjects`)
E.g.

```
//✔️ valid example: scene object accessing prefab
//This script is on a canvas element which is in the scene
public class MyCanvasXScript: MonoBehaviour
{
   //sdrag & drop prefab from the project pane to serialise a reference
   public GameObject myCharacterYPrefab; 
   
   private Start(){
      //instantiate myCharacterYPrefab, etc.
   }
}
```

But you are not able to serialize references to GameObjects in the Scene in a Prefab's script. E.g.

```
//❌ invalid example: prefab accessing scene object
//This script is on the Character Y prefab asset which is not in the scene
public class MyPrefabZScript: MonoBehaviour 
{ 
   //you cannot drag & drop references from the scene here
   //however, you are able to serialise other prefabs here
   public GameObject mySceneGameObject; 

   private Start(){
      //this will not run unless the prefab is in the scene
   }
}
```

It can be confusing that both prefabs and scene object references can be stored in the same field, so I recommend using a suffix or some naming standard to reduce the chance of logic errors.

Additionally, it's important to note that if Character Y doesn't exist in the scene (by placement in the scene or code runtime instantiation), the function `Start()` in Z script attached to it will not run.